# ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined

Tags: web3js, metamask

Hey guys i am trying to implement metamask's signTypedData login. I am getting the first part correctly, but i am having problem with second part where i need to verify signedtypeddata with eth.util.checksumaddress. i am getting this message on console

```
App.js:163 ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at Object.eip712Hash (sign-typed-data.ts:389:1)
    at recoverTypedSignature (sign-typed-data.ts:570:1)
    at signTypedDataV4Verify (App.js:145:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
```

This is my code

```js
const signTypedDataV4Verify = async () => {
    const chainId = 1;
    const msgParams = {
      domain: {
        chainId,
        name: "Ether Mail",
        verifyingContract: "0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC",
        version: "1",
      },
      message: {
        contents: "Hello, Bob!",
        from: {
          name: "Cow",
          wallets: [
            "0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826",
            "0xDeaDbeefdEAdbeefdEadbEEFdeadbeEFdEaDbeeF",
          ],
        },
        to: [
          {
            name: "Bob",
            wallets: [
              "0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB",
              "0xB0BdaBea57B0BDABeA57b0bdABEA57b0BDabEa57",
              "0xB0B0b0b0b0b0B000000000000000000000000000",
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      primaryType: "Mail",
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: [
          { name: "name", type: "string" },
          { name: "version", type: "string" },
          { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
          { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
        ],
        Group: [
          { name: "name", type: "string" },
          { name: "members", type: "Person[]" },
        ],
        Mail: [
          { name: "from", type: "Person" },
          { name: "to", type: "Person[]" },
          { name: "contents", type: "string" },
        ],
        Person: [
          { name: "name", type: "string" },
          { name: "wallets", type: "address[]" },
        ],
      },
    };
    try {
      const from = web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const sign =
        "0xe5d78d669361f4c6e8ee3d4b10122bdd8b5147e1478d3b531722cd8901fff27b6715436fe18013e2acb7a978aba4bab98330d92caf2c6a5ad0525493d5d257111c";
      const recoveredAddr = recoverTypedSignature({
        data: msgParams,
        signature: sign,
        version: "V4",
      });
      if (
        web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(recoveredAddr) ===
        web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(from[0])
      ) {
        console.log(`Successfully verified signer as ${recoveredAddr}`);
        console.log(recoveredAddr);
      } else {
        console.log(
          `Failed to verify signer when comparing ${recoveredAddr} to ${from}`
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
```

I hard coded the public key for simplicity in `from` variable

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply defining the Buffer like this:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
window.Buffer = window.Buffer || Buffer;
```

For this to work, you may need to install buffer first:

```
npm install buffer
```